# Rails hang on Devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, freeze, bcrypt

Have just integrated Devise (and Omniauth) into our website, replacing a from-scratch login system we had originally.

Everything is going nicely & the omniauth is working with Twitter & Facebook, but for some reason, when I click the login button, rails locks up completely.

The process will only end if I force quit using `sudo killall -KILL ruby`. Trying to kill the process by `Ctrl+C`, closing the terminal window or running a normal `kill` command is fruitless.

I went into activity monitor & sampled the process after it hang. This is what it showed:

```
Path:            /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
Load Address:    0x1022cf000
Identifier:      ruby
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  bash [51219]

Date/Time:       2013-09-15 20:03:47.540 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A558)
Report Version:  7

Call graph:
    768 Thread_6385293   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 768 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff8e8a35fd]
    +   768 main  (in ruby) + 79  [0x1022cff1f]  main.c:38
    +     768 ruby_run_node  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 78  [0x10230b4fe]  eval.c:251
    +       768 ruby_exec_internal  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 111  [0x10230b5af]  eval.c:204
    +         768 rb_iseq_eval_main  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 712  [0x102418898]  vm.c:1478
    +           768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +             768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +               768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                 768 rb_require_safe  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 939  [0x10230e33b]  load.c:620
    +                   768 rb_load_internal  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 302  [0x10230de2e]  load.c:310
    +                     768 rb_iseq_eval  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 405  [0x102417f85]  vm.c:1464
    +                       768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                         768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                           768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                             768 rb_obj_tap  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 14  [0x10235497e]  object.c:566
    +                               768 rb_yield  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 99  [0x1024154c3]  vm.c:670
    +                                 768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                   768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                     768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                       768 t_run_machine_without_threads(unsigned long)  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 9  [0x102d0fe69]  rubymain.cpp:223
    +                                         768 evma_run_machine  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 43  [0x102d018bb]  cmain.cpp:88
    +                                           768 EventMachine_t::Run()  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 288  [0x102d09060]  em.cpp:503
    +                                             768 EventMachine_t::_RunSelectOnce()  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 668  [0x102d09bdc]  em.cpp:924
    +                                               768 ConnectionDescriptor::Read()  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 231  [0x102d05177]  ed.cpp:781
    +                                                 768 ConnectionDescriptor::_DispatchInboundData(char const*, int)  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 234  [0x102d0532a]  ed.cpp:846
    +                                                   768 event_callback_wrapper(unsigned long, int, char const*, unsigned long)  (in rubyeventmachine.bundle) + 86  [0x102d11706]  rubymain.cpp:196
    +                                                     768 rb_funcall  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 252  [0x10241365c]  .vm_eval.c:456
    +                                                       768 vm_call0  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 798  [0x1024148ee]  .vm_eval.c:66
    +                                                         768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                           768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                             768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                               768 rb_f_catch  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 72  [0x102416df8]  .vm_eval.c:1547
    +                                                                 768 rb_catch_obj  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 170  [0x10241655a]  .vm_eval.c:1571
    +                                                                   768 catch_i  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 64  [0x10241bdc0]  vm.c:670
    +                                                                     768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                                       768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                                         768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                                           768 proc_call  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 112  [0x102310970]  proc.c:555
    +                                                                             768 rb_vm_invoke_proc  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 156  [0x10241745c]  vm.c:686
    +                                                                               768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                                                 768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                                                   768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                                                     768 proc_call  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 112  [0x102310970]  proc.c:555
    +                                                                                       768 rb_vm_invoke_proc  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 156  [0x10241745c]  vm.c:686
    +                                                                                         768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                                                           768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                                                             768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                                                               768 rb_class_new_instance  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 41  [0x102354e99]  object.c:1643
    +                                                                                                 768 vm_call0  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 798  [0x1024148ee]  .vm_eval.c:66
    +                                                                                                   768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                                                                     768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                                                                       768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                                                                         768 rb_hash_each_pair  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 80  [0x102324c90]  hash.c:214
    +                                                                                                           768 rb_ensure  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 109  [0x10230c27d]  eval.c:744
    +                                                                                                             768 hash_foreach_call  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 29  [0x102321fcd]  hash.c:197
    +                                                                                                               768 st_foreach  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 526  [0x1023b779e]  st.c:826
    +                                                                                                                 768 hash_foreach_iter  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 40  [0x1023277f8]  hash.c:164
    +                                                                                                                   768 each_pair_i  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 23  [0x102326d47]  hash.c:1292
    +                                                                                                                     768 rb_yield  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 99  [0x1024154c3]  vm.c:670
    +                                                                                                                       768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
    +                                                                                                                         768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
    +                                                                                                                           768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
    +                                                                                                                             768 bc_crypt  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle) + 101  [0x103169bc5]  bcrypt_ext.c:42
    +                                                                                                                               768 _crypt_blowfish_rn  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle) + 44  [0x103169ddc]  crypt_blowfish.c:736
    +                                                                                                                                 394 BF_crypt  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle) + 5862,5431,...  [0x10316b5d6,0x10316b427,...]  crypt_blowfish.c:658
    +                                                                                                                                 373 BF_crypt  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle) + 8011,7996,...  [0x10316be3b,0x10316be2c,...]  crypt_blowfish.c:683
    +                                                                                                                                 1 BF_crypt  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle) + 3857  [0x10316ae01]  crypt_blowfish.c:649
    768 Thread_6385298
    + 768 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff930fafd9]
    +   768 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 137  [0x7fff930f673a]
    +     768 _pthread_body  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 138  [0x7fff930f68a9]
    +       768 thread_timer  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 455  [0x102427817]  .thread_pthread.c:1159
    +         768 __select  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff9176f9aa]
    768 Thread_6385312
      768 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff930fafd9]
        768 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 137  [0x7fff930f673a]
          768 _pthread_body  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 138  [0x7fff930f68a9]
            768 thread_start_func_1  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 194  [0x102427c02]  .thread_pthread.c:657
              768 thread_start_func_2  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 539  [0x102427e4b]  thread.c:466
                768 rb_vm_invoke_proc  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 156  [0x10241745c]  vm.c:686
                  768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
                    768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
                      768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
                        768 rb_f_loop  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 51  [0x102416e63]  .vm_eval.c:863
                          768 rb_rescue2  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 434  [0x10230bff2]  eval.c:647
                            768 loop_i  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 40  [0x10241bd48]  vm.c:670
                              768 vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
                                768 vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018
                                  768 vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
                                    768 rb_f_sleep  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 48  [0x102378e10]  process.c:3472
                                      768 sleep_timeval  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 203  [0x10241fe7b]  thread.c:908
                                        768 native_sleep  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 434  [0x102427a82]  .thread_pthread.c:918
                                          768 gvl_acquire  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 163  [0x102423fa3]  .thread_pthread.c:309
                                            768 _pthread_cond_wait  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 727  [0x7fff930f8c4b]
                                              768 __psynch_cvwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff9176f716]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):
        11       vm_call_method  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 1003  [0x10241df4b]  .vm_insnhelper.c:404
        11       vm_exec  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 118  [0x102418046]  vm.c:1236
        11       vm_exec_core  (in libruby.1.9.1.dylib) + 9152  [0x10240e650]  insns.def:1018

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        BF_crypt  (in bcrypt_ext.bundle)        768
        __psynch_cvwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        768
        __select  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        768

Binary Images:
       0x1022cf000 -        0x1022cffff +ruby (0) <0F7F30F0-8062-3716-B431-250C34895147> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
       0x1022d8000 -        0x10248bfff +libruby.1.9.1.dylib (0) <60E1FBFF-51B5-3726-A5C9-38633E79652B> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
       0x1026f0000 -        0x1026f1fff +encdb.bundle (0) <1AE82D0A-C6D5-361F-BB07-6B2E1516CE31> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/encdb.bundle
       0x1026f4000 -        0x1026f5fff +transdb.bundle (0) <2DBEC619-C4C3-3718-8D23-AB553BD60D9F> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
       0x1026f8000 -        0x1026fdff7 +pathname.bundle (0) <F48F1DD6-38B5-3003-BBA7-EBCEB007AAE6> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/pathname.bundle
       0x102704000 -        0x102705fff +etc.bundle (0) <056C7371-A495-3B01-8013-1745F9DABF32> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/etc.bundle
       0x102709000 -        0x102709fff +sha1.bundle (0) <353A6930-BEC6-3389-AC52-20D944CD6054> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle
       0x10270c000 -        0x102819ff7 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <F3709008-4ABA-3A83-9746-06A430787F5A> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10288c000 -        0x1028c9fff +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <4491BFC1-1EB0-30C7-8F60-A2CB8A16C957> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x1028e3000 -        0x1028e4ff7 +digest.bundle (0) <89618AA0-E654-35A1-BC14-33B9D922892B> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest.bundle
       0x1028e9000 -        0x102905fff +socket.bundle (0) <C59B03F6-5F96-380B-B56A-A5DBCED437C4> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/socket.bundle
       0x102915000 -        0x102915ff7 +fcntl.bundle (0) <36208BE4-0D05-324B-AA2B-B67E59896A02> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/fcntl.bundle
       0x102918000 -        0x102947ff7 +openssl.bundle (0) <F685C024-5B0F-3566-913B-9D05E25C0A7E> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle
       0x102976000 -        0x10297afff +stringio.bundle (0) <4EBFCD7E-B6FD-36E8-9E7B-E672C012386D> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/stringio.bundle
       0x10297f000 -        0x102982ff7 +strscan.bundle (0) <38ABE381-E416-347E-AB4E-F81CBD70509A> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/strscan.bundle
       0x102987000 -        0x10298aff7 +psych.bundle (0) <CCA37E77-6AA3-38D1-8B38-915B44895A9C> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/psych.bundle
       0x102990000 -        0x1029a9ff7 +libyaml-0.2.dylib (0) <0204D764-6B99-32AA-93CF-BC5F9C310872> /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
       0x1029ad000 -        0x1029e2fff +date_core.bundle (0) <B027821A-7706-323D-B98A-1C482FB4D212> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/date_core.bundle
       0x102a00000 -        0x102a10fff +bigdecimal.bundle (0) <48410C0E-EF2B-3CFA-B85E-B38BC2645364> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/bigdecimal.bundle
       0x102a17000 -        0x102a1cff7 +mysql2.bundle (0) <C8DBA6D6-8069-3915-86AD-11C0251CF58C> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
       0x102a26000 -        0x102cc3fff +libmysqlclient.18.dylib (0) <C8EC5DA0-029C-395A-A3C5-D55A76C0CDFE> /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
       0x102d00000 -        0x102d17fff +rubyeventmachine.bundle (0) <8B3C3EAA-A920-31A2-AF13-A90C0649FC6D> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
       0x102d3b000 -        0x102d3eff7 +thin_parser.bundle (0) <AC71063A-558A-37AF-886A-D9AFE87312AD> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin_parser.bundle
       0x102d43000 -        0x102d45ff7 +cparse.bundle (0) <A973085A-E301-35E9-995B-E7C92852770A> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/racc/cparse.bundle
       0x102d49000 -        0x102d52fff +zlib.bundle (0) <AC9EA838-1047-32DD-95CF-6704434825C5> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/zlib.bundle
       0x102d5b000 -        0x102d5bfff +md5.bundle (0) <0BAF8986-87EB-36ED-98DE-393D62DA680A> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/md5.bundle
       0x102d5e000 -        0x102db0ff7 +RMagick2.bundle (0) <B668B3DD-178A-3E25-AA4D-D48C599C9822> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
       0x102dd3000 -        0x102f11fff +libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib (0) <53982A0A-0E2D-3A22-8D78-86E56C21BE48> /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.1.dylib
       0x102f42000 -        0x102fa6ff7 +libfreetype.6.dylib (0) <C7DD008E-7FA3-38F7-BAB8-47E8BDFB28E1> /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
       0x102fbb000 -        0x102fc0ff7 +libltdl.7.dylib (0) <357F1D41-A0FD-398E-B863-04FEFF09067D> /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
       0x102fc4000 -        0x102fc7ff7 +parser.bundle (0) <EFC9F9A6-3AC9-3FEB-A959-D6DD0BAEBF06> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
       0x102fcc000 -        0x102fccfff +utf_16be.bundle (0) <5723354B-E1CC-33B7-B486-7861A0AABED7> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/utf_16be.bundle
       0x102fcf000 -        0x102fcfff7 +utf_16le.bundle (0) <F0B89D8C-0342-3E04-8909-EEBD908EA334> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/utf_16le.bundle
       0x102fd2000 -        0x102fd2ff7 +utf_32be.bundle (0) <3D85353A-9547-31B9-BE75-C203F1303612> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/utf_32be.bundle
       0x102fd5000 -        0x102fd5ff7 +utf_32le.bundle (0) <DF3182FE-875F-30AB-857B-8E66CC22210B> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/enc/utf_32le.bundle
       0x102fd8000 -        0x102fdefff +generator.bundle (0) <350325AF-71F6-371B-8548-7F5EC1E8ADBC> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/ext/generator.bundle
       0x103169000 -        0x10316dfff +bcrypt_ext.bundle (0) <1DF6C61B-19D6-36B6-A5D0-0BCDED39BA8E> /Users/jamesbillingham/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle
    0x7fff6216f000 -     0x7fff621a2817  dyld (239.3 - ???) <6D8B6C0B-9A59-302E-B15E-1C65277318AC> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8be8d000 -     0x7fff8be9eff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <BAD0F7BE-5276-3D3F-8EA6-4F6C0498D07B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8c155000 -     0x7fff8c184fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <BA34F13D-FB96-309E-87EB-384F0313B594> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff8c19d000 -     0x7fff8c1a7fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <7EA072FE-46EB-3AF6-A688-8AD84466B591> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8ce60000 -     0x7fff8ce65ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <C278E08B-5AF2-333E-981C-83EB4B1B1188> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff8cf65000 -     0x7fff8cf67ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <AB5EDE3B-2637-3311-B952-7843CD60FAE9> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8cfb2000 -     0x7fff8cfb6ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <CB94932A-6601-3502-B001-1E9137C649ED> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8d49a000 -     0x7fff8d4a0ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.1.4) <6DF822C4-14D9-3E24-8A38-59332EAA972C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8d51e000 -     0x7fff8d547ff7  libc++abi.dylib (48) <8C16158F-CBF8-3BD7-BEF4-022704B2A326> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8dce4000 -     0x7fff8dcffff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.1.9.0.1) <6FD92CAA-EAE3-31F7-AA01-99AD73241DB7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8de83000 -     0x7fff8de84ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8e896000 -     0x7fff8e89fff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <D50F3BA7-ECAE-3823-825E-289CD352CCF8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8e8a0000 -     0x7fff8e8a3ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.3) <CD100014-1516-3187-AE76-8D30CBE12DCC> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8fb53000 -     0x7fff8fba1fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8fbcf000 -     0x7fff8fc03fff  libssl.0.9.8.dylib (50) <B15F967C-B002-36C2-9621-3456D8509F50> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8ff43000 -     0x7fff8ff4afff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <ED7E4CDD-38A5-38F7-BEE0-E343CCDCD206> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff901e2000 -     0x7fff9038ff8f  libobjc.A.dylib (551) <2D5D6788-5779-36B9-AC09-93BD9392BA4B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff90390000 -     0x7fff90398fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.1.11) <D13A6FB3-859B-3898-90E7-5752D35404C4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff90c69000 -     0x7fff90c6aff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <F73DF6AC-710E-3540-AF52-602FBDE61B9F> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff90ed1000 -     0x7fff90f5aff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.1.1) <6A38E4B6-137C-3BE6-85F8-BC40A85ECD91> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff90fc0000 -     0x7fff90fd1ff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff9168e000 -     0x7fff91693fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <C627F3A7-8424-31DC-94A6-E02B691D9923> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff91758000 -     0x7fff91759fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <334A82F4-4AE4-3719-A511-86D0B0723E2B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff9175a000 -     0x7fff91776ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.1.63.0.1) <7E884783-FACB-3397-AF32-A6441934ED40> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff91b8c000 -     0x7fff91b93ff7  liblaunch.dylib (842.1.1) <050D7CD9-DAF9-3EC9-BC6A-8A7A21532638> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff91fa7000 -     0x7fff91fa9ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.12) <DCC0A3B1-21B3-3F2F-A3AC-98EF19E15749> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff92fdf000 -     0x7fff92fecff0  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <0B98AC35-B138-349C-8063-2B987A75D24C> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff930f5000 -     0x7fff930fcff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.3) <E714B8DD-3749-3814-8E0A-F22DBE0A59BC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff9391a000 -     0x7fff9393efff  libxpc.dylib (300.1.16) <8A549529-C540-3CBA-89A7-3CF1A1604353> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff93ae2000 -     0x7fff93b24ff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff93ddf000 -     0x7fff93e06ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <92D574B5-1034-3032-9938-52E683AE10D5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff94724000 -     0x7fff94725ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <51B2EDB7-FED4-3D51-B789-3B89EBA06F28> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff949c5000 -     0x7fff949c9ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.1.25.0.1) <B07CF0D0-C45F-3624-A648-C0FC05D46F84> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff94a4c000 -     0x7fff94a4dfff  libunc.dylib (28) <0BDEAE3D-6920-3A10-A21D-A28B0021B575> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff95350000 -     0x7fff95351ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <9B7231DA-E9D9-3DA3-AED7-73ED0AEE76F4> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff95352000 -     0x7fff953a4fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff95627000 -     0x7fff95706fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (50) <26933882-0E57-3245-953D-6C3255865139> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff975eb000 -     0x7fff975f2ff3  libcopyfile.dylib (103) <22734271-8BD8-30CF-A163-EBE26EE58E8F> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff9779c000 -     0x7fff977b6fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.1.9) <34CC0B0C-BAF1-3F20-974E-129D4E65A0E3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff980dc000 -     0x7fff980dcff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <2AD973B7-F65B-37A6-8951-E0DC4EF41B96> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff98e04000 -     0x7fff98e05ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.9) <E081B01A-36DF-3CBE-9645-F4E53416726E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff990f2000 -     0x7fff99119ffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <E5BA67F2-9845-364A-8A91-DE43AB09A23A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
```

Based on the end of the first thread, it looks as though bcrypt could be the issue. I'm really not at all sure how to interpret this though.

The file & line referenced is here: https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt/blob/master/crypt_blowfish/crypt_blowfish.c#L649

It looks like a reference to an external binary, so I have no idea where to go from here with regards to diagnosing the issue.

Some help understanding this & any information as to possible causes would be greatly appreciated :)

---

**EDIT:** actually, it seems like maybe it didn't hang. It just took 31.1 minutes...

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-15 19:45:00 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[REDACTED]", "user"=>{"login"=>"[REDACTED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (5.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (lower(username) = '[REDACTED]' OR lower(email) = '[REDACTED]') LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[REDACTED]", "user"=>{"login"=>"[REDACTED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_without_sidebar.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1866822ms (Views: 30.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

At this point, I'm kinda confused. I think it probably still was bcrypt taking a long time, but I can't see any reason for that to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it was a fairly simple error of configuration.

Essentially I just set the bcrypt complexity level way too high. The calculations are `2^x` where `x` represents the complexity level.

The setting I originally had was:

```
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 25
```

The default value is `10`. I hadn't realized how much difference it would make since I wasn't aware of the exponential nature of the number.

I have now set it to `13` :)